# Loading test resources without Bundle in XCTest

Tags: xcode, xctest

I've a static library with a corresponding test target. The test target doesn't use a "Host Application". Within the test target, I've some test files in the folder `TestResources`, which I'd like to load.

The resources are copied, I see them in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<workspace>/Build/Products/<schema>-iphonesimulator/myLibraryTests.xctest/TestResources/`.

But

```objectivec
[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] URLForResource:@"TestResources/test" withExtension:@"json"];
```

doesn't work. There are no bundles at all! `[NSBundle allBundles]` returns `nil`.

So what can I do to get the path to my resources?

Comment: Ups, that was a typo, thanks. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bundle is there and the resources can be loaded!

Xcode gave me a false lead. I don't know why, but in the debug area, all variables are `nil`, despite "Debug executable" is enabled in the schema.